# Adding an integer to a sorted list - recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

I need to add int to a list recursively, and later on also add additional features.

```
def insert_in_list(x, tree):
    if not tree:
        return tree
    elif isinstance(tree[0], list):
        return inserting(x, tree[0]) + inserting(x, tree[1:])
    elif x < tree[0]:
        tree.insert(0, x)
        return tree
    else:
        return inserting(x, tree[1:])
```

I'm using `insert()`. But for some reason my list seems to be restricted to 3 values. For example

```
>>> insert_in_list(2, [1,5,10]) 
[2,5,10]
```

What happened to the `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your last case discards the first value. You'll first call `insert_in_list(x, tree)` and end up in case 4, where it will call `insert_in_list(x, [5, 10])`. Then that will end up in case 3 and insert `x` at the first position and then returns the new list `[2, 5, 10]`.

It's probably easier to deal with indices:

```
def insert_in_list(x, tree, index=0):
    if not tree:
        return tree
    elif x < tree[index]:
        tree.insert(index, x)
        return tree
    else:
        return insert_in_list(x, tree, index+1)
```

I just left out the second case because it was irrelevant for your question:

```
>>> insert_in_list(2, [1,5,10])
[1, 2, 5, 10]
```

Note that if your `tree` is sorted you can also do bisection instead of recursion to find the place where the values should be inserted. For example with recursive bisection and based on [`bisect.insort_right`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Lib/bisect.py#L3-L20):

```
def insert_in_list(x, tree, lo=0, hi=None):
    if not tree:
        return tree

    if hi is None:
        hi = len(tree)
    if lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if x < tree[mid]: 
            hi = mid
        else: 
            lo = mid + 1
        return insert_in_list(x, tree, lo, hi)

    tree.insert(lo, x)
    return tree
```

Comment: However, I think this might be the wrong approach.. We're working with binary trees in Uni. The function should be able to put any number into the list, but also if necessary create an empty list if a "leaf" turns into an inner node. For example:

    >>> our_tree = insert(5, [ ])          
    5
    >>> our_tree = insert(10, our_tree)  
    [[], 5, 10]
    >>> our_tree = insert(7, our_tree)   
    [[], 5, [7, 10, []]]
    >>>  our_tree = insert(1, our_tree)
    [1, 5, [7, 10, []]]

Comment: @AntonHansson I'm not sure what you mean with "tree" and "inner nodes". The point I was trying to make is that you should avoid destructive operations in your case. The "index" was just one option. But if you have follow-up questions you can simply ask a new question. :)